# Take laplacian of unevenly sampled data in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of unevenly sampled (1-D) data in the form of x and y values that I would like to take the laplacian  of. Is there an easy way to do this in numpy/scipy?

I was thinking of taking the gradient of the gradient, but wouldn't that introduce artifacts, even in evenly sampled data? eg, given the data `0,0,0,4,8,8,8` and 1d laplace operator `1,-2,1`, the laplacian would be `0,0,4,0,-4,0,0`, but using the gradient of the gradient would yield `0,1,2,0,-2,-1,0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of arriving at the `[1, -2, 1]` operator for evenly spaced grids is to either compute the first derivatives with a forward difference scheme, and the second with a backwards difference scheme, or viceversa, since both yield the same result. So a good option for your uneven grid is to do it both ways and then average the results.

Lets say we are looking at a grid point which is `hb` ahead of the previous grid point, and `hf` behind the next one:

```
--+----+----+---
 x-hb  x   x+hb
```

If I didn't mess my algebra, your Laplacian at `x` computed as the average described above would be:

```
(f(x+hf)*(1+hb/hf) + f(x)(2+hb/hf+hf/hb) + f(x-hb)(1+hf/hb)) / (2*hf*hb)
```

You can compute this on a 1D array doing:

```
def laplacian(x, y):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    hb = x[1:-1] - x[:-2]
    hf = x[2:] - x[1:-1]
    y_hb = y[:-2]
    y_hf = y[2:]
    hb_hf = hb / hf
    hf_hb = hf / hb
    return (y_hf*(1+hb_hf) - y[1:-1]*(2+hb_hf+hf_hb) +
            y_hb*(1+hf_hb)) / 2 / hb / hf

>>> laplacian(range(7), [0,0,0,4,8,8,8])
array([ 0.,  4.,  0., -4.,  0.])
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool! I don't know why I never thought to use slicing to do operators like that, I had always assumed I'd have to use a loop. Are there any resources on techniques like that?

Comment: I think you did mess the algebra a little bit: it should be `- f(x)(2+hb/hf+hf/hb)`, rather than positive.

Comment: Could you also give me some hints on how to do uneven laplace on 2D data?